# Vertically align text inside an element with a percentage height?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

As I have an element with a percentage height I can't use the line-height hack. Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

```
<div height="100%">
    I want to be vertically aligned in the middle
</div>
```

Comment: A brilliant example of how ridiculous CSS is

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you want: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/priklady/vertical-align-valid-solution-en.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the height value of div, then set line-height: value_of_div_height. line-height 100% won't work because it will take value of text, not div element. It works with or without vertical-align, as long as height=line-height

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    display: block;
}
```

Alternative method if you want to do with a paragraph inside a div element: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center

```
DIV.container {
    min-height: 10em;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle }
...
<DIV class="container">
  <P>This small paragraph...
</DIV>
```

Comment: Which is why he most likely doesn't want the line-height hack, because it relies on a fixed height. Container height %age allows for a responsive design.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the font-size, and you know the number of lines of text you have.
You can wrap the text in a span. And use the following CSS on the span.

```
span {
    font-size:20px;
    margin-top:-10px; //half the font-size (or (font-size*number of lines)/2)
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}
```